# Some parts of the Scene View don't seem to render

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 3D game in the Unity Editor. When I started making the project 2 days ago, everything was fine until now. My issue cannot be described, but I can share the images of what happens in the Scene View as I get closer to objects:

**Here is when I am a bit far from objects. You can see the gray part starting to pop out from the bottom:**

[image: Here is when I am a bit far from objects. You can see the gray part starting to pop out from the bottom.]

**Here is the image as I get closer to the objects:**

[image: Here is the image as I get closer to the objects]

**As soon as get very close, you can see the objects disappearing. 2 of the 4 boxes are not visible completely, 1 is a bit out of render, and the capsule(the player) is completely invisible:**

[image: As soon as get very close, you can see the objects disappearing. 2 of the 4 boxes are not visible completely, 1 is a bit out of render, and the capsule(the player) is completely invisible.]

This has suddenly started to appear on my Unity Editor. Please help. I don't know if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong, or any setting is incorrectly set.

Ps:- Please do comment if you require any of my scripts or any other details. I don't ask questions very often so I don't have much idea as to what kind of information is required.

Comment: Hi @GameDev_Noob. Have you modify the clipping planes? Try to decrease the value of the near clipping plane in the camera component.

Comment: Is This First Person or Third Person? What is that capsule in the middle is it the player? I can't help if there is no better describe of the problem? can you share the Cube inspector maybe it doesn't have box collider so you are getting into it. Maybe the problem From the Movement Script or the camera. Can you share it?  Can you show the problem in a video. maybe recording full screen are Better.

Comment: This is the Scene View in the unity editor itself, and not in game. Yes, the capsule is the player. I don't think its the problem with any colliders, since I have been deving without such problems for two days, and the cubes were there from the beginning of the scene.

Comment: @AndoniRivera I am currently reinstalling Unity's latest version. I was using an old version in the images. If the problem persists, I will share a video of whats happening.

Comment: I have suprisingly figured out the problem, but not the solution yet. It is actually something to do with clipping planes values. It has been somehow automatically decreased for scene view's near planes, and so the near objects are not clipping. I don't know why, but it seems to happen after I add any kind of canvas to my game.

Answer (score 1):

**To everyone seeing this in the future, here is a very simple solution to the problem, if you face any issues.**

*I have tried, and you can try the following steps as well.*
1)When in the Scene View in Editor, click on the small camera icon on top of the **Scene View Window** and uncheck the option **Dynamic Clipping**. This should solve your issue.

2)Although this has nothing to do with the problem, however, there is a chance it is an Editor Bug, so I recommend updating your Editor to the latest version, to see if it fixes the issue.